# How should I populate my 201 Created response?

Tags: c#, rest, http, asp.net-core

Normally I expect DTOs to be returned from controller actions, however with a 201 response MDN says

> the new resource is returned in the body of the message

1. Does this mean that the domain object should be returned, or the DTO?
2. How do you access the created entity? Options are...

- Should the repository method return the created entity?
- Should the repository method return the created entity id and I use that to get the created entity?
- Should I return the entity sent in the request?
- Should I return null and not bother sending the value?

See below for my endpoint code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateExerciseAsync([FromBody] ExerciseDto exercise)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var model = exercise.ToDomain();
        var createResult = await _exerciseRepository.CreateExerciseAsync(model);

        if (createResult.IsFailed)
        {
            return Problem(createResult.ToString());
        }

        return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetExerciseByIdAsync), new {id = model.Id}, null);
    }
```

Comment: basically: do what makes the most sense in your use case.

Comment: It should return whatever is needed to be returned, or whatever is in the spec, if you have one. Maybe thats the DTO since DTOs are usually for the purpose of transferring the data from one system to another, but maybe not. We can't answer that for you

Comment: Personally, of those options, I don't believe you should ever return your domain model. Returning either an id or a DTO is fine, but one purpose of having DTOs is that they act as a seam between your consumers and your domain. If you need to refactor your domain model, for whatever reason, and you're directly returning a domain model, that can be a breaking change. But if you're returning a DTO, or just an id, you are insulating your domain, allowing you to change its structure without breaking consumers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.Does this mean that the domain object should be returned, or the DTO?** Returning a DTO might be a better idea. Some of the reasons are:

- Domain objects may contain some data that is not supposed to be shared with the outside world.
- Client applications that are consuming your API are dependent on the response body of your request, since they need to know how to deserialize it. Your DTOs serve as a "data contract" between the API and the clients. If you are returning your domain objects, a change to the domain class (e.g. renaming a property) will break all the clients of your API.

**2. How do you access the created entity?** This depends on your particular situation. As @Franz Gleichmann said in the comment, do what makes the most sense in your case.

- **Should the repository method return the created entity?** This approach might be fine if the repository has enough information to return the created entity. If this would require passing some additional data to the repository, or an additional requests to the database, then this might not be the best idea.
- **Should the repository method return the created entity ID and I use that to get the created entity?** If you have all the necessary information except the ID in the `model` object (which you probably do), this might be the best approach
- **Should I return the entity sent in the request?** To me personally, this doesn't make much sense. Since you wouldn't communicate any new information to the client, this is just an unnecessary bandwidth consumption.
- **Should I return null and not bother sending the value?** This is also a fine approach if it works for you. Since you are returning a URI of the newly created entity (`GetExerciseByIdAsync` action + entity ID), this provides the clients of your API with enough information to access the newly created entity. However, this will require the clients to send another request (but again, if it works for you, that's fine).